# Server Name required for IIS6 windows auth login since W7 upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, iis-6

I have an intermittent problem after clients have upgraded to W7. I'll try to explain the scenario:

- W7 Pro client, member of W2003 Domain with a bog standard User role.
- Using IE8, user accesses intranet website via a hostname managed in their hosts file (IIS6, protected by Windows Authentication) which is served by a web farm such that the site session is randomly served by SERVER1 or SERVER2. The webfarm runs as a remote WORKGROUP, not a domain and is not connected in any way to the user's domain.

Prior to the upgrade to W7 (previously running XP) the user simply typed in their username and password for the intranet server entering their user as user.name only.

Since moving to W7, the user now has to prefix the username with the server name (SERVER1/user.name) to login. This is a big problem as there is no way of knowing which server is serving the page on the authentication  so the user is having to try both SERVER1 and SERVER2 to get authenticated.

Has something changed in W7 which may be causing this? Does anyone have any suggestions for a fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the user's passwords weren't synchronised between the domain and the workgroup.

For some reason it seems that XP didn't bother with a domain challenge before passing through the login details, whereas W7 it has to authenticate against the domain first before sending on the details.